# DataBinding dynamically created jpegs in WPF

Tags: wpf, jpeg

In my WPF application I am creating jpeg files dynamically. They are being saved in bin/Debug or bin/Release.

I have a databound `WrapPanel` with an image control that is using a `ValueConverter` like so:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return new Uri(value.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
}
```

An example value for value is `Images\400\26.jpg` which I assume is by default looking in bin\Debug or bin\Release.

My problem is that I can't seem to be able to databind image controls to the dynamically created jpegs. But I can databind to other jpegs that I've marked as `Include` and whose `BuildAction` is `Content`.

How do I databind to the dynamically created images that aren't present at compile time?

Comment: You might try code behind as it might not be limited to files "included" in the project.

Image myImage3 = new Image();
BitmapImage bi3 = new BitmapImage();
bi3.BeginInit();
bi3.UriSource = new Uri("smiley_stackpanel.PNG", UriKind.Relative);
bi3.EndInit();
myImage3.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
myImage3.Source = bi3;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a collection of Images Paths, and add to it every newly created image's path. now you can bind your wrappanel to this collection.

You can implement this collection in ViewModel class, and then make this ViewModel class be your DataContext, and bind your wrapPanel to that collection using your converter.

Edit: Here is a sample files:

MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace wpfJpegBindingSample
{
    class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged 
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
        #endregion

        //constructor
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            m_imagesList = new ObservableCollection<Uri>();
        }

        //collection of images' Uris
        private ObservableCollection<Uri> m_imagesList;

        //property for the collection (so you can bind to it)
        public ObservableCollection<Uri> ImagesList
        {
            get 
            {
                return m_imagesList;
            }
        }

        //an Add method that update the bindings
        public void Add(Uri uri)
        {
            ImagesList.Add(uri);
            OnPropertyChanged("ImagesList");
        }

    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace wpfJpegBindingSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = m_viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }

        private MainWindowViewModel m_viewModel;
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="wpfJpegBindingSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesList}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see, in the view model we defined a collection of the Uris of images.
In the main window code behind we set an object of that view model as our window data context, and in the xaml we set the Item source of our listView (or any other control you choose) to binding of the property ImagesList, at our data context which is the view model.

Finally, we can modify your dynamically jpeg creator function:

```
        private void dynamicallyJpegCreator(string newImagePath)
        {

            // Creating Image code
            // .....
            // Create new image at newImagePath

            m_viewModel.Add(new System.Uri(newImagePath, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        }
```

At this point you'll get a listview displays list of dynamically created images

Comment: @Lee: I saw you upvoted my answer. Did it helped you? If it was, please mark it as the solution.